# VB.NET Webkit Javascript Alert Popup

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I made a live html editor in Visual Studio using the WebKit Webbrowser. Javascript works, but i cant figure out how to get javascript alerts to work.

https://gyazo.com/1962090a11f0b52e414171956156fb02

^^ as you can see in the code, Im trying to get a javascript alert box to popup when you click the button, but nothing happens. What should I do?

Please dont vote this down!